# Handling sweet alert using protractor

Tags: protractor

I am automating the one site where developer sets the sweet alerts with different values, data like Error! ,Success!, No Data Found! etc.
So I used the CSS selector but it gave me an error.

I am attaching the screenshot of that sweet alerts with inspect code, how can I debug this?

[image]

Comment: Can you add to the post what css selectors have you tried and what are the errors?

Answer (score 0):

css locator to ge the header like 'Error!':

```
div.sweet-alert > h2
element(by.css('div.sweet-alert > h2')).getText();
```

css locator to get the message content below the header:

```
div.sweet-alert > h2 + p
element(by.css('div.sweet-alert > h2 + p')).getText();
```